# Bounding box doesn't include children? threejsr85

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am facing problem where bounding box doesn't include children of the mesh. I have tried all the solutions like calling update() of the BoxHelper but didn't got any success. Please help me with the solution[image: bounding box coming wrong]

Code for the bounding box:-

```
var boxHelper = new THREE.BoxHelper(Object); // to remove the diagonals
this.scene.add(boxHelper);
boxHelper.material.color.set(0x00ff00);

boxHelper.update();
```

Comment: three.js r.69 is 3 years old. You will have to update to the current three.js version if you want help.

Comment: @WestLangley I updated the code as you suggested ... still got no success

Comment: No link is there

Comment: Can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/) and demonstrate the issue?

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/137/

Comment: BoxHelper works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/akmcv7Lh/138/